# Make a thread on Django - Stay in the 'try' action and never complete the 'except' action

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I have done a small thread (try - except) on python which is working on a .py file but when I aded it on my Django view.py and using from my front end, the behavior is weird.. It is staying in the 'try' and never test the except action.

```
try:
    print("############# I am in csv ###################")
    df = pd.read_csv(...)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("############# I am in JSON ###################")
    df = pd.read_json(...)
```

Actual result is sending me a ValueError:

```
############# I am in csv ###################
arrays must all be same length
############# I am in JSON ###################
```

and it keeps trying on the `df = pd.read_csv(...)` which send me an error when i'm uploading a json..

Expected result (which I get on a python file) would be:

```
############# I am in csv ###################
arrays must all be same length
############# I am in JSON ###################
```

`ValueError...`

and `df` is equal to the data I sent

If any of you have encountered the same issue, please, let me know !! I'm stuck on this for too much time now.

Thanks you all

Comment: It looks like it tries to parse JSON here. I'm not entirely sure what is not working according to you. If `pd.read_json` throws another exception, then of course it will print the error a second time.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to parse a JSON file. When I am using this thread with python and parsing my JSON file, it's working. 
When i do it on Django, it is not working anymore... Very weird.. I can't understand why

Comment: is it possible that the cursor of the file handler is located at the end of the stream after the first read?

Comment: I actually don't know.. How could I check that ?

Comment: You mentioned you have ```done a small thread```, perhaps show us it? As in how do you create the thread and start it etc.

Comment: Why not to add whole your **Django View** in ```try/except``` block ?. You will detect problem easily.